# How to handle risk of multiple callbacks under one function in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, settimeout, async.js

I am using async.map to handle multiple tasks, and for each task, I would like to set a timeout.

```
async.map(tasks, handleFunction, (error, callback))

I add the setTimeout inside handleFunction to return immediately,

const handleFunction = function(callback){

setTimeout(()=> {return setImmediate(callback, new Error())});

// handler logic, detail process code ...
// some http requests or file read and 

return callback();
}
```

Above, it is risky of returning multiple callback, one from normal process code(if task done successful), one from setTimeout.

My question is: is there any better way to avoid this. Cause currently solution may return two callback. I got following error: "Callback was already called."

Comment: Why are you putting `setImmediate()` inside of `setTimeout()`?  What are you hoping to accomplish with that?  Why not just use `setImmediate()`?  And, why did you not specify a time for `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set a flag for whether you already called the callback or not.  You can put this inside your `async.map()` handler:

```
let called = false;
function doCallback(err, data) {
   if (!called) {
       called = true;
       callback(err, data);
   }
}
```

And, then use `doCallback()` inside your `async.map()` handler instead of `callback()`.  If you call `doCallback()` more than once, it will do nothing.  Only the first call to it will be passed onto the actual async callback.

---

If you showed your actual code with all detail in place, we could also suggest a means of coding it that cancels the timer before it can fire if your calling the callback before the timer goes off and if the timer does fire, then sets a flag that you already timed out so you can check that flag before calling `callback()` when things complete.

---

You could also make yourself a callback timeout utility function that you can resuse anywhere you want this type of functionality.

```
// callback that times out
function timerCallback(t, timeoutErr, callback) {
    let called = false;
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            callback(timeoutErr);
        }
    }, t);
    return function(err, data) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            callback(err, data);
        }
    };
}
```

You'd then use it like this:

```
async.map(tasks, handleFunction, (error, callback))

    // create callback with debouncing and timeout
    let internalCallback = timerCallback(1000, new Error("timeout"), callback);

    // then do your async stuff and call internalCallback(err, data) when done
 }
```